# How to save following content as PDF in Angularjs using FileSaver.js

Tags: angularjs, api, filesaver.js

[image]

[image]

I am unable to save this content as proper PDF using FileSaver.js

---

this is Angular code

```
$http(
  { url:root.api_root+'/appointments/generatePDF/'+$route‌​Params.id,
    method:'GE‌​T'
}).then(function(r‌​es){ // 
    $log.log(res.data); 
    var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    window.open(res.data); 
    // saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
});
```

this is TCPDF Backend code

```
$pdf->Output("php://output", 'F'); 
echo file_get_contents("php://output");
```

Comment: For information on how to ask a question well, please see our [How to Ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: the content being set to the PDF document is Either `[object Object]` or  this format using JSON.stringify() `{"0":"%","1":"P","2":"D","3":"F","4":"-","5":"1","6":".","7":"7","8":"\n",`. I am unable to get the proper render able pdf

Comment: Please include the code that you are using to download the PDF file. It looks like the file has been corrupted by erroneously using UTF-8 decoding.

Comment: this issue has been partly fixed, @georgeawg you are right as you can see in the image due to character encoding the pdf is not rendering.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem **in the question itself.** See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is Angular code `$http({url:root.api_root+'/appointments/generatePDF/'+$routeParams.id,method:'GET'}).then(function(res){
        
//            $log.log(res.data);
             var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
           
            window.open(res.data);
//           saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
            
        });`

Comment: this is TCPDF Backend code `$pdf->Output("php://output", 'F');
        
        echo file_get_contents("php://output");`

Answer (score 6):

When downloading binary data such as PDF files, it is important to set the `responseType` property:

```
$http(
  { url:root.api_root+'/appointments/generatePDF/'+$route‌​Params.id,
    method:'GE‌​T',
    //IMPORTANT
    responseType: 'blob'
}).then(function(r‌​es){ // 
    $log.log(res.data);
    //var blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    //window.open(res.data);
    var blob = res.data; 
    saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
});
```

If the `responseType` property is omitted, the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) defaults to processing the data as UTF-8 text. The process of decoding the data as [UTF-8 text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) will corrupt binary files such as PDF or images.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR ResponseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Answer (score 2):

### Dependencies

- [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js)
- [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)
- [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/)

> ### Installation
>
> Using bower: bower install angular-file-saver
>
> Using npm: npm install angular-file-saver

### Basic usage

- Include `ngFileSaver` module into your project;
- Pass both `FileSaver` and `Blob` services as dependencies;
- Create a [Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) by
  passing an array with data as the first argument and an object with set of options
  as the second one: `new Blob(['text'], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })`;
- Invoke `FileSaver.saveAs` with the following arguments:

  - `data` **Blob**: a Blob instance;
  - `filename` **String**: a custom filename (an extension is optional);
  - `disableAutoBOM` **Boolean**: (optional) Disable automatically provided Unicode text encoding hints.

You can do so by injecting FileSaver and Blob into the controller and then using the syntax as shown below:

```
angular.module('sample',['ngFileSaver'])
.controller('ConsultationDetailsController', ['$scope', 'FileSaver', 'Blob', function($scope, FileSaver, Blob){
      $scope.download = function (fileName) {
                $scope.isLoading = true;

                downloadHttpService.getDocument(fileName)
                 .then(function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    var status = response.status;
                    var header = response.headers();
                    var fileType = header['content-type']; 
                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: fileType });
                    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, originalFileName);
                })
                    .catch(function (resp) {
                      // show error
                    })
                    .finally(function (data) {
                       // execute finally block.
                    });
            };
}]);
```

> if you want only the pdf type then you can hard coded define
>   fileType as 'application/pdf' like this var fileType= 'application/pdf';

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but answering a low-quality question usually attracts downvotes on the answers as well. Now to my comment - You're injecting `FileSaver` and `Blob` to the controller - Don't you need to inject the relevant dependencies to to your app module as well?

Comment: Yes, you have to inject 'ngFileSaver' to your main app module.

Comment: So [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43715244/edit) and include it in the answer (Add it in the actual code) and i'll upvote, since then it should be a complete answers (At least to me)

Comment: I have added the installation , dependencies and basic usage . Now you can refer to this. And let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Now that's a great answer! Hope it will help the OP

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan .  :)

Comment: I used ur code `var fileType = header['content-type']; 
                    var blob = new Blob([resp], { type: fileType });
                    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, originalFileName);` the content saving in file is "[object Object]"

Comment: @tphobe9312 for your case use `var fileType ='application/pdf '. It will work as you might not be returning the content-type in the header in correct way from Web api.

Comment: filetype is not the issue here,  I am unable to write the pdf content properly.

Comment: also I m not using Injecting Filesaver as dependency, I m using it globally like in jQuery, that may not be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me. Just try it.

```
$http(
  { url:root.api_root+'/appointments/generatePDF/'+$route‌​Params.id,
    method:'GE‌​T'
}).then(function(r‌​es){
    $log.log(res.data);     
    saveAs('data:application/pdf;base64,' + res.data, 'file.pdf');
});
```