# Angular doesn't download a file eventhough the HTTP status is 200

Tags: angularjs, file, download, multipart

I have created a method which should download a file from DB. The whole method at frontend side returns status 200, but the whole files looks:

`Java` controller:

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('CLIENT', 'WORKER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(@RequestParam("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File file = fileService.downloadFile(id); //custom File class
        if (file == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        }
        byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(file.getData());
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "pdf"));
        header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.getName());
        header.setContentLength(file.getData().length);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).body(base64Bytes);

    }
```

`JS Controller` file:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function (id) {
            FileService.get({id: id}).$promise.then(function(result) {
                console.log('download file');
            });
        }
```

`HTML` file:

```
<li>
<button ng-click="downloadFile(f.id)">{{f.name}}</button>
</li>
```

In the browser I have:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715032/how-to-save-following-content-as-pdf-in-angularjs-using-filesaver-js/43715244#43715244)

Comment: I don't want to upload. The case is to download file from db in the web browser

Answer (score 0):

Try Content-Disposition: attachment instead of Content-Disposition: inline.

Comment: Try to not encoding your data, just return byte array. It works for me.

Comment: It's an actual behaviour, you see bytes of your file. Java part is OK. Are you sure that you don't modify headers in Angular?

Comment: I haven't changes the js code since I posted the question so it is the same as above

Comment: Could you try to execute request from something like Postman or DHC and download the content as a file? You will be sure that bytes array is not corrupted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143192/discussion-between-bielas-and-xaepe).

Answer (score 0):

For easier implementation, have a look on [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver).

First you need download and include the path for the `angular-file-saver` plugin:

`<script src="libs/angular-file-saver.bundle.js"></script>`

Remember to include the `ngFileSaver` in your angular module:

`angular.module('app', ['ngFileSaver']);`

And also inject `FileSaver`and `Blob` dependencies to your download file controller:

`app.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'FileSaver', 'Blob', function ($scope, FileSaver, Blob) {`

Now the implementation part:

First you need to convert base64 bytes to Blob

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
   contentType = contentType || '';
   sliceSize = sliceSize || 512; // sliceSize represent the bytes to be process in each batch(loop), 512 bytes seems to be the ideal slice size for the performance wise 

   var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
   var byteArrays = [];

   for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
         byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
   }

   var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
   return blob;
}
```

Lastly, just use the `angular-file-saver` plugin to finish the job

```
var blob = b64toBlob(fileData.documentStream, fileData.contentType);
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileData.name + '.' + fileData.extension);
```

Hope this helps.