# In Angular 5 how can I force a download of a PDF retrieved from an authenticated API

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, angular5

I have an API endpoint which uses authentication.  The endpoint is a GET endpoint however I can not simply load it into a browser because the endpoint is looking for an authentication token in the header.  So. In order to get the data from the endpoint I have created a service (which uses an extension of the httpClient object that automatically puts in the proper authentication headers.  This is how my service call looks (simplified):

```
getReceipt(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('the/url', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

And this is what it looks like when i do the call in my component:

```
this.myService.getReceipt().subscribe(data => {
    console.log('receipt data');
    console.log(data);
});
```

So everything is working, but I can't figure out how to do the next step which is actually making the pdf download.  Note: the "receipt data" that i log in the console looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.3
%����
1 0 obj
<</Author <> /Creator (cairo 1.14.6 (http://cairographics.org))
  /Keywords <> /Producer (WeasyPrint 0.42 \(http://weasyprint.org/\))
  /Title (Receipt)>>
endobj...
```

I don't know what format this is, but I'm guessing that this is raw pdf data in it's native format.  How can i force this to data to download?

Note also, I have searched many posts on SO and tried a few things.  The following is something I tried that almost worked:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'the/url';
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

What this did was force a download, however because the token was not properly in the header all I got was a message from the backend saying "Invalid Token" instead of my actual pdf.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use filesaver.js to prompt browser to show the download option after getting the pdf in binary format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715032/how-to-save-following-content-as-pdf-in-angularjs-using-filesaver-js

Comment: set the responeType as `blob` or `responseType: "arraybuffer"` as required  in the http call

Comment: ding ding ding ding ding!! and the winner is blob for 2 points...  Please post as answer and i will accept

Comment: Ok most of the cases this is due to incorrect responseType only :)

Comment: posted it as answer as mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using incorrect `responseType` to return PDF documents. It should be 
`responseType: 'blob'` in your case . So your http call should look like below -

```
getReceipt(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('the/url', {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```